# prove $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Here is my thinking:
by definition, $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})=\sigma(\mathscr{R})$, where $\mathscr{R}=\{R_1\times R_2:R_i\in\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\}$.

I am confused about $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$. What is $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$? Can I write $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})=\sigma(\mathscr{E})$, where $\mathscr{E}=\{(k,m):k,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Similarly, can I write $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})=\sigma(\mathscr{G})$, where $\mathscr{G}=\{k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal P(X)$? I mean what's the definition?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. The power set of $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @copper.hat. Its definition is in product measure space. Definition: $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})=\sigma(\mathscr{R})$, where $\mathscr{R}=\{R_1\times R_2:R_i\in\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\}$. To be more general, suppse $\mathscr{F_1}$ and $\mathscr{F_2}$ are sigma algebra, then $\mathscr{F_1}\otimes\mathscr{F_2}$ is defined by $\sigma(\mathscr{R})$, where $\mathscr{R}=\{A_1\times A_2:A_1\in\mathscr{F_1}, A_2\in\mathscr{F_2}\}$.

Comment: Both sides are $\sigma$ fields. $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}) \subset \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ follows immediately from this definition, and since $\mathscr{R} =\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ you are finished.

Comment: @copper.hat. As I mentioned above, I do not how to represent an element in $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$. Once I know, I can write down more details about the proof.

Comment: You wrote that it is the power set of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. An element of this has the form $A \times B$, where $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You are correct that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) = \sigma(\mathcal E)$.  This is because $\mathcal E = \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, and $\sigma(\mathcal E) = \mathcal P(\mathcal E)$ because $\mathcal E$ is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So clearly $\mathcal P(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \otimes \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.  Now pick any element $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)$.  Since $A$ is countable, it can be written as
$$ A = \{(a_k,b_k):k\in\mathbb N\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{a_k\} \times \{b_k\} .$$
Hence $A$ is in the sigma algebra generated by all sets of the form $U \times V$ where $U,V \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

This works because the underlying set is countable.